# Sequents in which succedents are restricted to one formula

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus, sequent-calculus

In the original version of Sequent Calculus by Gentzen for classical and intuitionistic propositional logic there is a structural difference: the classical version admits succedents with multiple formulas but the intuitionistic version admits only succedents with one formula.

I'm searching for another formulation of Sequent Calculus in with succedents are restricted to one formula both for classical and intuitionistic logic.
In particular I'm searching for a formulation in which Sequent Calculus for classical logic is obtained by Sequent Calculus for intuitionistic logic by adding some rule (i.e. excluded middle).

Can someone suggest me some reference?

Comment: The right place to start with is Negri & von Plato, [Structural proof Theory](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Structural_Proof_Theory/ZvACGkn9138C).

Comment: Nice, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :-)